# Dates in between the Date Range - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, date

I have a table which holds:

```
PlaceID, STARTDATE, ENDDATE, OCCUPANCY  
100, Jan 1, Jan 10, Occupied  
100, Jan 15, Jan 20, Occupied  
100, Jan 11, Jan 14, Empty  
100, Jan 21, Jan 31, Empty  
200, Jan 10, Jan 15, Occupied  
200, Jan 25, Jan 31, Occupied  
200, Jan 01, Jan 09, Empty  
200, Jan 16, Jan 24, Empty
```

For a date, say Jan 22, I want to know what was its Occupancy on different PlaceIDs.

The Result I need is:

```
PlaceID, OCCUPANCY  
100, Empty  
200, Empty
```

My problem is I can't find the Occupancy inbetween STARTDATE and ENDDATE.

Comment: What query are you running to select the records exactly?

Comment: What data-type are STARTDATE and ENDDATE?

Comment: What result must be returned when: a) two separate rows with different `Occupancy` matches the date in interest b) none row mathces the date. PS. If you want to say "this situation is impossible" - prove it by showing table's DDL with according constraint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple-minded pseudo-code query would be:

```
select PlaceID, OCCUPANCY from Occupancy
where STARTDATE >= 'Jan 22' and ENDDATE <= 'Jan 22'
```

If duplicate entries are possible:

```
select distinct PlaceID, OCCUPANCY from Occupancy
where STARTDATE >= 'Jan 22' and ENDDATE <= 'Jan 22'
```

However, this all depends on whether the STARTDATE and ENDDATE columns are
real date columns.

Otherwise, you could define them as numeric and present "Jan 22" as "2206".

Comment: Is Distinct really necessary?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio: Only in case multiple entries are possible. Otherwise, not.

Comment: Thanks @harrymc , The where clause works for me if it is this way,
STARTDATE <= 'Jan 22' and ENDDATE >= 'Jan 22'

Comment: Thank you all for your valuable time